# Oracle SQL - Get DDL for entire schema

Tags: sql, oracle

I wanted to have DDL for the entire schema(tables,view,Index, Procedure, Function, Trigger etc..) of an Oracle DB. Is there a way to get the combined ddl rather than doing one by one for each table /function/ view.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use

```
dbms_metadata.get_ddl
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Do you mean executing the following query?

SELECT DBMS_METADATA.get_ddl ('TABLE', table_name, owner)
FROM   all_tables
WHERE  owner      ='username';                                                     

In this case we have to generate the DDL for each table/view one by one.. I would like to find some ways where I can get DDL for all the tables/views.

Comment: The thread indicated in the duplicate closure reason shows you how to do this.